# MYSQL Import Pipe Delimited Data

Tags: mysql

I would like import a huge csv file with lines like below

AD|ANDORRA|||AIXIRIVALL|ALV|25999|25999|ALV|

The columns in my database are lets say A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I

I would like to know how my import statement for MYSQL database should look like

Appreciate the help

Thanks,

Comment: Start by reading [some documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the dataset, I often use http://nimbletext.com/

Set the column separator to pipe and then you should be able to put in something like

```
('$0','$1','$2','$3','$4','$5',$6,$7,'$8','$9'),
```

for the pattern.

Add an insert clause, remove the final comma and you're done.

Nimble text works fairly well for a result up to about 500k lines.  It gets very slow if you are creating multiple lines for each input line.